# Add values from Pandas row to dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe in Pandas that has columns that will correspond to the key and value of a dict.

```
for values in ['A','B']:
    MYDICT[values] = [] # Initialize to empty list

Name    ID    othercolumns
A       5     ...
B       6     ...
A       3     ...
```

I am trying to find a simple way to assign every value of Name to ID so `MYDICT[NAME].append(ID)`

The solution I currently have is to iterate over every row in the dataframe

```
for index, x in df.iterrows():
    WINNERS[x['Name']].append(x['ID'])
```

Is there a better way to do this without having to use `iterrows()`?

Comment: You can not assign the same key to dict

Comment: What is your expected output ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group by `Name` and aggregate `ID` into a list

```
WINNERS = df.groupby('Name')['ID'].apply(list).to_dict()
WINNERS
```

Out:

```
{'A': [5, 3], 'B': [6]}
```